# Modelling Sum of Dependent Random Variables using Copula or Vines

Tags: distributions, copula, independence

Let's say I have a multivariate dependent RVs $C_i$, and each $C_i$ is a function of RVs $X$ and $Y$. I know marginal distribution of $C_i$. In my case it is a truncated Laplace distribution.

I want to model or approximate the distribution of sum of $C_i$, i.e., $\sum_i C_i$. It looks like another truncated Laplace distribution. After browsing, I found that people usually use the copula and a graphical model called vines.

Questions:

1. Can I model the distribution of $\sum_i C_i$ using copula or vines? Since I'm not familiar with both tools (in fact, this is my first time doing a research on dependent RVs), which one is more tractable?
2. Since I'm working with truncated RV, it seems that the support of the distribution of $\sum_i C_i$ is bounded on a certain value that is less than when you assume they are independent (the support is the support of convolution of each $C_i$). Can I use the copula or vines as well?
3. I also found that for correlated Log-Normal RVs, there is the Felson-Wilkinson approximation. Have you heard any approximation for the truncated Laplace distribution?